# In TestNG how to exclude some methods when running complete package

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, testng

My testNG.xml file looks like below:

```
<suite name="Suite-3" verbose="1">
  <test name="all-packages">
    <packages>
      <package name=".*" />
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

It executes all the test cases in this package, but how can I exclude some of the test methods written in some classes inside this package?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<suite name="Suite-3" verbose="1">
  <test name="all-packages">
    <packages>
      <package name=".*" />
    </packages>
    <classes>
      <class name="your.package.name.Classname">
        <methods>
          <exclude name="methodName1"/>
          <exclude name="methodName2"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

If class is located inside one of packages that are presented in `packages` tag, it will not run twice, but all methods from `exclude` tag will be removed from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use "enabled = false" in @Test annotation above your test method or class.

```
@Test(enabled = false)
 public void testingA() {
   System.out.println("Test Success");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include or exclude methods from a class using:

```
<suite name="Sample Test Suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Method Test Cases" >
    <classes>
       <class name="com.easy.entry.AddTestCase">
        <methods>
        <include name="addLocationTestCase" />
        <include name="addDepartmentTestCase" />
        <exclude name="addEmployeeTestCase" />
      </methods>
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```